# Making this slider rotate infinitely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rotation, slider

I'm trying to make this a slider for a site and I'm having trouble making this slider rotate its images. what I want to get is when I click next on the last image it would back to the first image and the same with the previous button. the code works if i make the adjustments i made into a comment. any help would be very helpful!thanks!!

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  var Slider = function() {
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments)
  }
Slider.prototype = {

  initialize: function(slider) {
    this.ul = slider.children[0]
    this.li = this.ul.children

    // make <ul> as large as all <li>’s
    this.ul.style.width = (this.li[0].clientWidth * this.li.length) + 'px'

    this.currentIndex = 0
  },

  goTo: function(index) {
    // filter invalid indices
    if (index < 0 || index > this.li.length - 1)
      return

    // move <ul> left
    this.ul.style.left = '-' + (100 * index) + '%'

    this.currentIndex = index
  },

  goToPrev: function() {
    this.goTo(this.currentIndex - 1)
  },

  goToNext: function() {
    /* this is the code im trying on but it wont work
        if (this.currentIndex = 0) {
      this.goTo(this.currentIndex + 1)
     };
     else if (this.currentIndex = 1) {
      this.goTo(this.currentIndex + 1)
     };
     else if (this.currentIndex = 2) {
      this.goTo(this.currentIndex + 1)
     };
     else*/
    this.goTo(this.currentIndex - 3)
  }
}
var sliders = []
$('.slider').each(function() {
  sliders.push(new Slider(this))
})
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider > ul {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s left;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s left;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s left;
  -o-transition: 0.5s left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.slider > ul > li {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">

  <div class="slider">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="img1.jpg">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img2.jpg">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img3.jpg">
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <a href="javascript:sliders[0].goToPrev()">Prev</a>
    <a class="butnav" href="javascript:sliders[0].goTo(0)">1</a>
    <a class="butnav" href="javascript:sliders[0].goTo(1)">2</a>
    <a class="butnav" href="javascript:sliders[0].goTo(2)">3</a>
    <a href="javascript:sliders[0].goToNext()">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some modification in the code and it's working for me.

```js
var Slider = function() {
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  };
  Slider.prototype = {

   initialize: function(slider) {
    this.ul = slider.children[0];
    this.li = this.ul.children;

    // make <ul> as large as all <li>’s
    this.ul.style.width = (this.li[0].clientWidth * this.li.length) + 'px';

    this.currentIndex = 0;
   },

   goTo: function(index) {
    // filter invalid indices
    if (index < 0 || index > this.li.length - 1)
      return;

    // move <ul> left
    this.ul.style.left = '-' + (100 * index) + '%';

    this.currentIndex = index;
   },

   goToPrev: function() {
    if(this.currentIndex === 0){
     this.goTo(2);
    }else{
     this.goTo(this.currentIndex - 1);
    }
    
   },

   goToNext: function() {
    if(this.currentIndex === 2){
     this.goTo(0);
    }else{
     this.goTo(this.currentIndex + 1);
    }
   }
  };
  var sliders = [];
  $('.slider').each(function() {
    sliders.push(new Slider(this));
  });
```

```css
.slider {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .slider > ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s left;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s left;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s left;
    -o-transition: 0.5s left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .slider > ul > li {
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide">
  <div class="slider">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/590405794153136128/fdGjhrrv.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
     <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/3c/af/cf/3cafcf31f34af16b7f833f0bd844c856.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
     <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT-l-xbQ1bUZMCrbTvm_qbAwZOdJEWYBg3e23OrLmRl72LcWhsJfQ">
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation">
   <a href="javascript:sliders[0].goToPrev()">Prev</a>
   <a class="butnav" href="javascript:sliders[0].goTo(0)">1</a>
   <a class="butnav" href="javascript:sliders[0].goTo(1)">2</a>
   <a class="butnav" href="javascript:sliders[0].goTo(2)">3</a>
   <a href="javascript:sliders[0].goToNext()">Next</a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: If you want that  after last image it should not go reverse back to first image then change the CSS accordingly.